# Display user location on the map MapboxJS

Tags: javascript, geolocation, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

It seems as though it is not possible to [Show the user's location on the map](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/beta/maps/examples/user-location/) using Mapbox-gl-js. There are examples in the documentation that discuss doing this with Mapbox IOS/Android however, nothing with MapboxGl JS.

**What I've Tried:**
I am currently able to add a Geolocate Control that does this feature with a button:

```
map.addControl(
    new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
        positionOptions: {enableHighAccuracy: true},
        trackUserLocation: true,
        showUserHeading: true,
    })
);
```

However, this is not live tracking of the user, as shown in the linked example above.

Is anoyone able to help?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right - GeolocateControl will track the user on the map as a blue pulsing dot. If it's not doing that for you, something is going wrong - perhaps you haven't granted permissions, or perhaps you're not running in a context where the browser can get the user's location. For instance, you need to be serving the page on `https`, not `http`.